# Using VpnService to block some IPs (KitKat vs 4.3 and below)

Tags: android, networking, vpn

Morning folks,

I have tried to modify VPN sample (ToyVPN) to work as a simple firewall to block some outgoing traffic. I decided to do it the following way:

- Create a VPN Connection for some IPs only
- Do nothing in the VPN handling code :)

Which seems easier than assessing the packets and act according to their contents.

This seems to work well for Android 4.3 but on 4.4 I receive an error:

```
...
09-03 06:02:11.340    1806-1897/com.example.android.toyvpn E/ToyVpnService﹕ Got java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '43 interface fwmark rule add tun0' failed with '400 43 Failed to add fwmark rule (No such device)'command '43 interface fwmark rule add tun0' failed with '400 43 Failed to add fwmark rule (No such device)'
...
```

Here is my VpnService Builder code:

```
    Builder builder = new Builder();
    builder.setMtu(30000);
    builder.addAddress("10.0.0.1",24);
    builder.addRoute("212.77.100.101",32); // this is a sample IP I use for tests 

    mInterface = builder.setSession(mServerAddress)
            .setConfigureIntent(mConfigureIntent)
            .establish();
```

Run code I have does nothing:

```
while (true){
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Log.e(TAG,"Running");
           }
```

In result I get what I want - traffic to my manually entered IP is routed to a /dev/null kind of interface :)

I do believe my issue with KitKat is related to some bugs/issues in Android 4.4 (e.g. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63349 but there a more VPN related ones).

But I know that what I try to achieve is doable - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netspark.firewall is a proof that works well on my 4.4 phone. And its done via VpnService as the same VPN pop-up cames when using this app.

Could you please help me understand what am I doing wrong and how to get VpnService operational on 4.4 ... not really to do VPN-ing but rather some simple firewall-ing.

This all applies to non rooted devices.

PS. Is there some limitation on the number of IPs (IP subnets) I can add to VpnService this way?

Comment: Interesting fact - the code works on 4.4 device, fails on 4.4 Emulator. Works on 4.3 emulator though ??

Comment: After various testing I realized that VPN Service works significantly different on Emulator 4.3 vs 4.4 ... not so much difference on real device though. I believe that was the source of all the issues I had.

Answer (score -1):

I hava do this issue,first you must understand android VpnService give you ParcelFileDescriptor,in this you can get ip packet,it can be cast to Linux iphdr * pointer ,so you get the packet srcIP and dstIP dstPort,you can choose drop or traffic this packet.if you have another issue  you can build tcp or udp packet from ip packet,at this level you can get host ip and website .